# Error when loading a module for a dogle in a toradex colibri imx6 ( insmod )

Tags: linux, module, drivers, imx6

I want to use an Edimax N150 usb dogle in a toradex colibri imx6 , and for that I need to cross compile the deprecated driver RTL8188cu (  which is also the same as RTL8192cu ) , which I did against the linux Kernel of the Toradex colibri, It didn't compile at the begenning since there were a lot of deprecated methods , but I managed to make them updated by replacing them with the new ones and it compiles and generates me the module 8192cu.ko , Now I load them on the colibri and when I do an Insmod I get the following error :

```
[   95.186137] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol alloc_etherdev_mqs
[   95.192907] 8192cu: Unknown symbol alloc_etherdev_mqs (err -22)
[   95.223690] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol skb_copy_bits
[   95.229983] 8192cu: Unknown symbol skb_copy_bits (err -22)
[   95.239004] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol skb_put
[   95.244826] 8192cu: Unknown symbol skb_put (err -22)
[   95.250329] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol __netif_schedule
[   95.256956] 8192cu: Unknown symbol __netif_schedule (err -22)
[   95.263550] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol unregister_netdev
[   95.270190] 8192cu: Unknown symbol unregister_netdev (err -22)
[   95.270203] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol skb_dequeue
insmod: ERROR: could not insert m[   95.270207] 8192cu: Unknown symbol skb_dequeue (err -22)
odule 8192cu.ko: Invalid paramete[   95.270241] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol dev_alloc_name
rs
[   95.270245] 8192cu: Unknown symbol dev_alloc_name (err -22)
[   95.270279] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol unregister_netdevice_queue
[   95.270282] 8192cu: Unknown symbol unregister_netdevice_queue (err -22)
[   95.270304] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol wake_up_process
[   95.270308] 8192cu: Unknown symbol wake_up_process (err -22)
root@colibri-imx6:~# [   95.270318] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol eth_type_trans
[   95.270321] 8192cu: Unknown symbol eth_type_trans (err -22)
[   95.270381] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol netif_device_attach
[   95.270384] 8192cu: Unknown symbol netif_device_attach (err -22)
[   95.270393] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol skb_queue_tail
[   95.270396] 8192cu: Unknown symbol skb_queue_tail (err -22)
[   95.270452] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol skb_pull
[   95.270456] 8192cu: Unknown symbol skb_pull (err -22)
[   95.270487] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol skb_push
[   95.270490] 8192cu: Unknown symbol skb_push (err -22)
[   95.270510] 8192cu: no symbol version for wireless_send_event
[   95.270514] 8192cu: Unknown symbol wireless_send_event (err -22)
[   95.270522] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol register_netdev
[   95.270526] 8192cu: Unknown symbol register_netdev (err -22)
[   95.270538] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol free_netdev
[   95.270542] 8192cu: Unknown symbol free_netdev (err -22)
[   95.270611] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol __pskb_pull_tail
[   95.270614] 8192cu: Unknown symbol __pskb_pull_tail (err -22)
[   95.270622] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol netif_rx
[   95.270625] 8192cu: Unknown symbol netif_rx (err -22)
[   95.270631] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol __netdev_alloc_skb
[   95.270634] 8192cu: Unknown symbol __netdev_alloc_skb (err -22)
[   95.270645] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol skb_trim
[   95.270649] 8192cu: Unknown symbol skb_trim (err -22)
[   95.270688] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol __dev_kfree_skb_any
[   95.270691] 8192cu: Unknown symbol __dev_kfree_skb_any (err -22)
[   95.270720] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol netif_carrier_off
[   95.270724] 8192cu: Unknown symbol netif_carrier_off (err -22)
[   95.270737] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol skb_copy
[   95.270740] 8192cu: Unknown symbol skb_copy (err -22)
[   95.270746] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol skb_clone
[   95.270750] 8192cu: Unknown symbol skb_clone (err -22)
[   95.270755] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol dev_get_by_name
[   95.270759] 8192cu: Unknown symbol dev_get_by_name (err -22)
[   95.270767] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol netif_carrier_on
[   95.270770] 8192cu: Unknown symbol netif_carrier_on (err -22)
[   95.270783] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol find_vpid
[   95.270787] 8192cu: Unknown symbol find_vpid (err -22)
[   95.270828] 8192cu: disagrees about version of symbol register_netdevice
[   95.270831] 8192cu: Unknown symbol register_netdevice (err -22)
```

I searcheg for the file Module.symvers in the kernel of the toradex and I found it , I tried to copy it in the module.symvers of the driver but when I compile it the file is erased , thank you if you can help me solving the problem or helping me with any way.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the latest (3.14.52) Colibri iMX6 kernel from Toradex has `CONFIG_RTL8192CU=m` in the [Colibri iMX6 defconfig](http://git.toradex.com/cgit/linux-toradex.git/tree/arch/arm/configs/colibri_imx6_defconfig?h=toradex_imx_3.14.52_1.1.0_ga#n136).

There should be no need to compile the driver out-of-tree.  I'd recommend simply deploying/building the latest kernel & modules.  You can [download the latest binary image from the Toradex Developer Center](http://developer.toradex.com/software/linux/linux-software#Binary_Images).